# Angular ng Serve Command Error during running my project

Tags: angular-cli

When I tried to run the existing angular project it gets compiled but throw the Error Message like this.

"Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **"

Cannot find module '@angular/core/package.json'

when I tried to build it shows the error

You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error.

Versions I am using are

```
node version -> v8.11.3, 
npm version ->  5.6.0, 
and CLI ->  7.3.1.
```

But it compiles fine when I create sample project using angular tutorial.

I'm  new to Angular,Please any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your dependencies try to remove node_modules 
and install it again and also try the command **npm run audit**